# Getting an error "Unsolved Reference: ActivityMainBinding" while implementing BindView to the MainActivity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

While implementing `bindView` in my MainActivity.kt file it shows an error

> Unsolved Reference: ActivityMainBinding

error in this line in MainActivity.kt:

```
private lateinit var binding: com.example.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.aboutme

import android.content.Context
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: com.example.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layout.activity_main)
 ...
}
```

Applied data binding to **Application level gradle file** as below.

```
dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

wrapped the root layout inside layout as below.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...
...
</layout>
```

Comment: Pls add your Activity's code. Also, comment `private lateinit var binding` first and then clean> rebuild the project.

Comment: @Astha I've updated the code, Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: I still don't see `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layout.activity_main)` code.

Comment: Pardon me, I did it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **Build -> Rebuild Project** after implementing the BindView, and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Plugin,

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and also use,

`kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'`

in your dependencies